# Are there any Grafana dashboards available for Vespa metrics?

Tags: vespa

We're using the exporter (https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa_exporter) to get Vespa metrics into Prometheus. Are there any Grafana dashboards available that could be exported and shared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just exported the vespa metrics dashboard we use and added it to the dashboards on grafana.com.

https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11018

I hope it will get you started. You will most likely have to tweak it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is great!